# My json array is not working in ionic framework using cordova

Tags: arrays, json, cordova

i need to fetch json array from url and show it in ionic list.
I am fetching data successfully from the url but unable to show list

My code is :

home.ts file

```
        import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  public testing : any = [];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: HttpClient) {
    this.ionViewDidLoad();
  }

  ionViewDidLoad()
  {

    this.http.get('http://kuranishqip.com/endrrat/api/categories.php')
        .map((response: Response) => response)
        .subscribe(data => {
        this.testing = data;
        console.log(this.testing);
        /*
        for(var i of data)
        {
            this.testing.push(i.count);
        }
        */
    },err => {
        console.log(err);
    }
    );
  }

}
```

And html file is

home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list *ngFor="let testing of test">
        <ion-item>
            <h2>{{test.count}}</h2>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

i am successfully showing json array in my console log, but having problem in transferring data to html file.

Comment: The file which you are saying is ts is that a provider ts file ?

Comment: no its home.ts file

Comment: Edited the description. Please check now

Comment: Ok so where and when are you calling the getResult() method

Comment: i am directly calling in home.ts file. i have edited the description please check it now

Comment: Ok did you try adding a async pipe on your html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not used the correct way for looping your testing array. Instead you should use like this in your html. 
And one more thing there is no need to trigger the ionViewdidLoad() or any ionic navigation events inside the constructor, it will trigger automatically when ever the page loads.

```
*ngFor="let test of testing"
```

And then use binding inside for to access test and its properties like test.propertyName

This means you are assessing each item in your case test of the array testing please change this and try